# Are remote flash files vulnerable?

Tags: flash, security

Currently I'm allowed users to add application/x-shockwave-flash objects to their profiles in my website. I've only filtered the URL and the content-type is set to "application/x-shockwave-flash"

Is there any vulnerabilities in allowing my users to link to remote flash/video files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be safe in principle, assuming that the users only specify a file (they don't write the embed code), and that they cannot upload files to your server.

You might care to make use of the `allowNetworking` and `allowScriptAccess` parameters in the embed tag where you embed the SWF, to limit what these embedded SWFs are allowed to do. See [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/secure_swf_apps_04.html) for details.

Also, I'm assuming you don't have a wide-open crossdomain.xml file on your server. If you all open crossdomain access, then I think it's possible that hotlinking to unknown SWFs could be unsafe. (If you don't have any crossdomain.xml policy file, you're fine - the default is for no access to be granted if no policy exists.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the user-generated Flash content will be hosted on other domains, it'll be sandboxed in the Flash player and won't be able to access anything critical on *your* domain.